# How to show and hide login and logout buttons in AppBar when other component logs in / out using localstorage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, material-ui

I have a `App` component which renders `MyAppBar` component which has Login and Logout button. `App` also renders `Login` form component which have a button that adds user information to local storage performing dummy successful login functionality. Login button is supposed to show Login form, however I have omitted this functionality for simplicity. Logout button clears localstorage performing dummy successful logout functionality. Both functionalities are working:

- a button in `Login` component is able to add value to localstorage
- Logout button in MyAppBar component is able to clear localstorage

Doubts:

**Q1.** how do I hide Login button and show Logout button, when a button in `Login` component adds value to localstorage?
**Q2.** how do I hide Loout button and show Login button, when a Logout button in MyAppBar component clears localstorage?
**Q3.** "Most importantly", how can I do both without re-rendering the AppBar?

**MyAppBar.js**

```
import { AppBar, Button, Toolbar } from "@material-ui/core";
import "./styles.css";

export default function MyAppBar() {
  const logout = () => {
    localStorage.removeItem("user");
  };
  return (
    <AppBar>
      <Toolbar>
        <Button color="inherit">
          Login
        </Button>
        <Button onClick={logout} color="inherit">
          Logout
        </Button>
      </Toolbar>
    </AppBar>
  );
}
```

**Login.js**

```
import { Button } from "@material-ui/core";

export default function Login() {
  const login = () => {
    localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify({ name: "rnj" }));
  };
  return (
    <>
      <Button variant="contained" color="inherit" onClick={login}>
        CREATE USER IN LOCALSTORAGE
      </Button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Check whole code in action in [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/hide-login-logout-e3ulp) codesandbox. You can run the codesandbox in new browser window by hitting [this](https://e3ulp.csb.app/) link, so that you can use DevTools to check changing localstorage.

Answer (score 1):

Well you can use useState and useEffect in order to do this.
Basically you can replace your login and MyAppBar Code like this.

**Login.js**

```
import { Button } from "@material-ui/core";

export default function Login() {
  const login = () => {
    localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify({ name: "rnj" }));
    window.location.reload();
  };
  return (
    <>
      <Button variant="contained" color="inherit" onClick={login}>
        CREATE USER IN LOCALSTORAGE
      </Button>
    </>
  );
}
```

**MyAppBar.js**

```
import { AppBar, Button, Toolbar } from "@material-ui/core";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function MyAppBar() {
  const [isLogged, setisLogged] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    checkStorage();
    return () => {};
  }, [isLogged]);
  function checkStorage() {
    if (localStorage.getItem("user")) {
      setisLogged(true);
    } else {
      setisLogged(false);
    }
  }
  const logout = () => {
    localStorage.removeItem("user");
    setisLogged(false);
  };
  return (
    <AppBar>
      <Toolbar>
        {!isLogged ? (
          <Button color="inherit">Login</Button>
        ) : (
          <Button onClick={logout} color="inherit">
            Logout
          </Button>
        )}
      </Toolbar>
    </AppBar>
  );
}
```

For just demo purpose I have reload the page when you will create user but I will prefer you to just pass the loggedIn state as props and then change the state in Login.js so you will be able to hide/show button without reload.
I hope this will work for you.
Thanks